Proofs about Infinite Unions and Intersections
I am currently learning proofwriting through self-studying. In my studies, I found the following proposition:

This proof made me think about proofs involving the intersection or union of infinite sets. The above proof outlines a clear strategy for dealing with the intersection of infinite sets. Namely, the proofwriter chose particular sets from the infinite collection of sets to narrow down the possible values for the entire intersection. In this case, considering $A_0$ and $A_1$ allowed the author to narrow down potential members to two, which was sufficiently small for the second sub-proof of the larger proof. This sub-proof, along with the first sub-proof (the converse subset argument), made it possible for the author to avoid dealing with the boundless nature of the sets.
An infinite union, on the other hand, seems a bit more daunting. Indeed, while any additional intersection can only serve to preserve or constrict the pre-existing intersection, any additional union can only serve to preserve or expand the pre-existing union. So, how does one go about proving what the union of infinite sets is?

There is no general recipe, do you have a specific example that you need assistance with?

@copper.hat No. I was curious about seeing a sample.

Try the above example with intersection replaced by union.

$$\large\cup_{z\in\mathbb Z}[z,z+1)=\mathbb R$$

Arbitrary (possibly infinite) unions are defined by an existential quantifier, just like intersections are defined by a universal quantifier.
In general there is one additional problem with unions that most intersections don't have: the a priori requirement that elements belong to a given universe of which all the individual $A_a$ are subsets - otherwise there is no logical guarantee that the result is even a set.
Intersections have this problem only in the pathological case where the index set is empty. The requirement to belong to "all" members of an empty family is logically equivalent to no requirement at all, meaning every element in the universe belongs to the intersection.
For practical calculations you can always use de Morgan's rule that the complement of a union is the intersection of the individual complements. Again, taking complementary sets presupposes that we have identified a universal set of all elements under consideration.
In your example the universe is always $\mathbb R.$
